# CRM 2011 Sub-Grid: Call JavaScript On-Click or On-Focus

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

How can JavaScript execute when a sub-grid receives focus?

I have a sub-grid that shows all Cases associated with an Account.
I would like to disable some fields on the form when the sub-grid receives focus.

RibbonDiffXML action for a ribbon button:

```xml
        <Actions>
            <JavaScriptFunction Library="$webresource:mda_convertemailtocaselib" FunctionName="ConvertEmailToCaseLib.addToCase">
              <CrmParameter Value="SelectedControlSelectedItemIds" />
            </JavaScriptFunction>
        </Actions>
```

This passes the sub-grid select items to a ribbon button, but I would like the JavaScript to execute before the ribbon button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried either of these out, but hopefully one of them should work for you.

1. Although it is a subgrid, there still is a control on the form.  Unfortunately there is no "supported" way to know when a control gets focus since there aren't any OnFocus/OnBlur methods exposed via the CRM JS API.  However you should be able to add your own JS event handler for that control and disabled the fields via the API `Xrm.Page.getControl("fieldname").setDisabled(true)`
2. I'm not 100% sure if this way would work, but it would be pretty sweet.  Create a CustomRule EnableRule.  In this CustomRule you call your own JS.  In this create a function where you disable the fields and then return true to make the button enabled.  It would look something like this:

```js
    function disableFieldsEnableRule() { 
        Xrm.Page.getControl().setDisabled(true);
        ...
        ...
        return true; // so the button is enabled
    }
```

The only reason I'm not sure if this will work is because I'm not sure if the Enable rules are checked each time you click on the subgrid or just the first time (I think it should be every time).  Also I'm not sure if you want those fields re-enabled once you click off.  If you do you might have to do something similar to this with a button on the native form, or something else.